# How can I get the current device model on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wrote a logger class that emails me when there's an exception on my application, but I'd like to know what the model of device is that threw the exception. For example:

```
Logger.LogError(App.ApplicationName, Device.OS.ToString(), "Error getting passenger ancillary transactions!", Settings.CurrentUsername, ex.ToString());
```

Sends an email of the exception with the application's name and the fact that the device is "Android" or "iOS", but nothing more specific than that. In Visual Studio, it says which device I'm about to debug on (like "iPod Touch" or "LG LS991"). Is there a way to access this information? I can't find anything in the Xamarin documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Xamarin.Plugins` by jamesmontemagno work cross-platform within `Xamarin.Forms`:

You would be looking for the `DeviceInfo` plugin:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/DeviceInfo

#### Nuget search: 'Device Info Plugin for Xamarin and Windows'

### Device Model

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the model of the device
/// </summary>
string Model { get; }
```

### Version

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the version of the Operating System
/// </summary>
string Version { get; }
Returns the specific version number of the OS such as:

iOS: 8.1
Android: 4.4.4
Windows Phone: 8.10.14219.0
WinRT: always 8.1 until there is a work around
```

#### Platform

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the platform of the device
/// </summary>

Platform { get; }

Returns the Platform Enum of:

public enum Platform
{
  Android,
  iOS,
  WindowsPhone,
  Windows
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Model` is what gets the actual model string.

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete SushiHangover's answer:
On iOS, Model property does not contain full model name(e.g. you cannot distinguish iPhone 3 and iPhone 4).

Fortunately, here is [some code](https://github.com/dannycabrera/Get-iOS-Model), that extracts it for you.

Comment: How would I use this from xamarin forms ?